# Possible to update rows with data only accessible via API call?

Tags: mysql, api

I'm not good at what I'm working on so apologies if some of my terminology is off. Also not sure if this belongs here, or in a more programming oriented area.

I am looking for options to update rows of a mysql database with data only accessible via REST api.

In other words... I will create a row with some of the data needed. Then I have 4-5 columns I'd like to update with data that I need to gather from the output from an API call

Answer (score 0):

- "Columns" look different (dates vs strings vs numbers); the values within a given column all look the same (eg, all are dates)
- "Rows" look similar, but with different values.
- A "table" is a collection of any number of rows, but of a fixed number of columns.
- An API call must go to some application language code (Java, PHP, or ...) which interprets the yucky REST syntax and proceeds to, for example, issue a `SELECT` (for a `GET` REST call) or `INSERT`/`UPDATE` (for a `PUT`), etc.  You must write this app code; MySQL does not understand REST.
- I suspect REST is so restrictive that a PUT is not allowed to return what a GET would return.  So, perhaps you have to do 2 API calls.  This also happens with talking to MySQL -- an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` merely says 'ok' or 'err'; you then need to do a `SELECT` to fetch stuff.

I hope this helps.  To continue this Q&A, please provide

- More details about your application.
- Whether you have settled on an app language to code REST in.
- Some hints of what column types your table(s) has.

(Otherwise, it will probably be closed as "too broad".)